# Inject Service in Karma with Typescript test

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm having same problem with make the test in my application. I started to use TypeScript and I still learning.

I'm facing this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: movieProvider <- movie
```

**movie.spec.ts**

```
import { MovieService } from './movie';

describe('service MovieService', () => {
  let movieService: MovieService;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('movieSearch'));

  it('should be registered', inject((movie : MovieService) => {
    expect(movie).not.toBeNull();
  }));
});
```

**movie.ts**

```
/** @ngInject */
export class MovieService {
  static $inject = ['$log', '$http', 'LoaderManager'];
  public apiMovieDetail: string = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/';

  /** @ngInject */
  constructor(private $log: angular.ILogService, private $http: angular.IHttpService, private loader: LoaderManager) {
  }

  public getMovie(id: string): angular.IPromise<IMovie> {
    this.loader.add();
    return this.$http.get(this.apiMovieDetail + '?plot=short&r=json&i=' + id).then((response: any): any => {
        this.loader.remove();
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error: any): any => {
        this.loader.remove();
        this.$log.error('XHR Failed for getMovie.\n', error.data);
      });
  }

}
```

I'm able to inject the controller with this code:

```
beforeEach(inject(($controller: angular.IControllerService) => {
    mainController = $controller('MainController');
}));
```

Comment: isnt the module beforeEach(angular.mock.module('movieSearch')); should be beforeEach(angular.mock.module('movieService')); ?

Comment: Thanks for  the comment @Sreekanth! This wasen't the problem, after alot of tests I already discovered, look bellow my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below injection was working. Injecting direcly the MovieService.

```
  beforeEach(inject((MovieService: MovieService, $httpBackend: angular.IHttpBackendService, $log: angular.ILogService) => {
    movieService = MovieService;
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    log = $log;
  }));
```

But when I make the test using the injection on "it" like below

```
  it('should be registered', inject((movie : MovieService) => {
    expect(movie).not.toBeNull();
  }));
```

He cannot resolve this second `MovieService`. If I use the `movieService` variable set on the 1 example works. Like below:

```
beforeEach(inject((movieService: MovieService) => {
    movieService = $httpBackend;
}));

it('should be registered', inject(() => {
    expect(movieService).not.toBeNull();
}));
```